# Greasemonkey/Javascript only executing halfway

Tags: javascript, for-loop, greasemonkey

**What I want to** do is a change the presentation of various elements/objects.

**The problem** is that the script stops executing at specific points (i will mark it in the code)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          fix
// @namespace     http://www.domain.se
// @description   fix
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==

var tablevar = document.getElementsByClassName('Table_new');
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('TabNavigation');

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.height = '67px';
    } //<-- works just fine
for(var i = 1; i < tablevar.length; i++) {
        tablevar[i].width = '130px';
    } //<-- works just fine
document.getElementById('customerbottom').style.margin="100px 1px 1px 1px"; //<-- executes
tablevar[0].width = 'auto'; //<-- does not execute
```

The wierd thinig is that when i change places for the two final rows it works for the first one. I just cant figure out why the script just stops.

It it's any help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

EDIT2: SOLVED!
By just using general statements and not targeting one specific object the scripts runs, but as soon as I target one specific object in an array or by ID the script stops.

Comment: Fixed it. Just missed it in the import (it's supposed to be tablevar)

Comment: are you sure you don't mean to do tablevar[0].style.width?

Comment: I've tried that as well. Its the same result. Just to give you the example. If i move this:
    *** document.getElementById('customerbottom').style.margin="100px 1px 1px 1px"; ***
to the beginning then that will be the only thing that is executed.

Whatever comes later does not execute. Same for tablevar[0].style.width (or just [0].width) for that matter. Whichever of these that comes first ends the script after that instruction.

Comment: So you are saying assigning the `.width =` works if it's before the `margin=` ?

Comment: Abe: No, Im saying that both of the last rows work independendly. The first one of the two is executed, then nothing else happens. If I'd move tablevar[0].width="auto"; to the beginning (after var declaration), then the script would set width=auto and not execute anything that comes after.

Comment: So as long as the instructions are in loops and not targeting one specific object in the array it works and the script runs smoothly, but as soon as I target one specific object (with ID or array[number]) the script only executes that instruction.

Comment: I notice the loop on tablevar starts at 1 instead of 0, so the problem may be to do with the first thing in the array? Might be good to get a jsfiddle going to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Also, if the array is empty, and there is no DOM element with a class of Table_new, that would explain the behaviour.

Comment: That is intentional. The first object in the array (first element with the class name) is the table itself. So I cant assign width="130px" when it has some 6 or 7 columns spanning 130px each.

Comment: The class Table_New is set to a table and all its TDs. The script works, but the problem lies within the last lines. Only the first will be executed, everything after it is ignores. And you can pick either of these.
document.getElementById('customerbottom').style.margin="100px 1px 1px 1px"; //<-- executes
tablevar[0].width = 'auto'; //<-- does not execute

Answer (score 0):

there is no width property for DOM element

it should be probably

```
tablevar[0].style.width = 'auto';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp

Comment: `<table>` and `<td>` tags have a `width` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the problem but it doesnt matter what I put there. All the single line arguments kills the script.